# How to generate 'required' Attribute in GWT using UIBinder?

Tags: html, gwt, uibinder

Expected HTML

```
<input class="sth" type="input" required/>
```

How to generate this using UIBinder in GWT?
I am using following and not generating the required attribute

```
<g:TextBox ui:field="username"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it in UiBinder with standard TextBox widget. If this is a one-off situation, set it in code. If this is something that you use often, create your own widget by extending TextBox and adding:

```
public void setRequired(boolean isRequired) {
    if (isRequired) {
        getElement().setAttribute("required", "required");
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in UiBinder:

```
<w:MyTextBox ui:field="username" required="true"/>
```

where `w` links to your widgets folder.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, your solution worked for me, and this way i am able to handle that from UIBinder. Additionally i noticed that we can achieve that in view as username.getElement().setPropertyBoolean("required", true); but this way we cannot handle using view. Thanks for your solution